# Question on Proof that the Fibonacci Word is Sturmian

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science, fibonacci-numbers, formal-languages, combinatorics-on-words

I am currently reading a text where it is proved that the infinite [Fibonacci Word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_word) $u$ defined as the limit of the sequence
$$
 u_n = \varphi^n(0)
$$
where the morphism is given by $\varphi(0) = 01, \varphi(1) = 0$ is [Sturmian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturmian_word), meaning for each $n$ there exists exactly one factor $u$ such that $u0$ and $u1$ are both factors of the word (such factors are called *right special*). Further the Fibonacci word is the unique fixed point of the morphism when extended to infinite words.

Now the proof goes like this ($F(f)$ denotes the set of factors of $f$))

> We show that the *Fibonacci* word
>   $$
>  f = 0100101001001010010100100101001001\ldots
> $$
>   defined in Chapter 1 is Sturmian. It will be convenient, in this chapter, to start the numeration of finite Fibonacci words differently, and to set $f_{-1} = 1, f_0 = 0$. Since $f = \varphi(f)$, it is a product of words $01$ and $0$. Thus the word $11$ is not a factor of $f$ and consequently $P(f,2) = 3$. The word $000$ is not a factor of $\varphi(f)$, since otherwise it is a prefix of some $\varphi(x)$ for a factor $x$ of $f$, and $x$ has to start with $11$.
>   To show that $f$ is Sturmian, we prove that $f$ has exactly one right special factor of each length.
>   We start by showing that, for no word $x$, both $0x0$ and $1x1$ are factors of $f$. This is clear if $x$ is the empty word and if $x$ is a single letter. Arguing by induction on the length, assume that $0x0$ and $1x1$ are in $F(f)$. Then $x$ starts and ends with $0$, and $x = 0y0$ for some $y$. Since $00y00$ and $10y01$ have to be factors of $\varphi(f)$, there exists a factor $z$ of $f$ such that $\varphi(z) = 0y$. **Moreover, $00y0 = \varphi(1z1)$ and $010y01 = \varphi(0z0)$, showing that $1z1$ and $0z0$ are factors of $f$**. This is a contradiction because $|z| \le |\varphi(z)| < |x|$. (and so on...)

I am not sure about the boldfaced part. Is it in general true that for an infinite word $w$ and a morphism, if $u = \varphi(v)$ where $u$ is some factor of $w$ we can conclude that $v$ is a factor of $w$? I am not sure, but maybe there is some property used about the Fibonacci word, can someone please explain the reasoning behind the boldfaced part?

Answer (score 4):

Basically what is being used is that $\varphi$ is injective:  if $\varphi(x) = \varphi(y)$ then $x = y$.  From this it follows that given any factor of $f$, we can deduce the "break points" it has where it factors into images of different letters of $f$.  For example
$00100$ must factor like $(0)(01)(0)t$ where $t$ is either $0$ or $01$.  So $00100$ in $f$ must arise as the image under $\varphi$ of $101u$ for some letter $u$.

Start with $00y00$ being a factor of $f = \varphi(f)$.  Since it starts with a $0$, this $0$ can only arise as the image of $1$ under $\varphi$.  On the other hand, it ends with $00$, which can only arise as the image of $10$ or $11$ under $\varphi$.  It now follows that $0y$ has to be the image of some $z$, and so $00y00$ must arise as the image of $1z10$ or $1z11$ under $\varphi$.

Similar reasoning applies to $10y01$.